# how to split pyspark dataframe into multiple dataframe of equal record count

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which I want to spilt into multiple dataframes of equal records. I am doing this task on AWS EMR and pandas or numpy is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create df_parts, a list of k equally sized dataframes, assuming k divides df row count

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('ID', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df_parts = [df.where((F.col('ID') - F.lit(k) * F.floor(F.col('ID') / F.lit(k)) == F.lit(i)) for i in range(k)]
```